# Web service in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

I have an ASP.NET MVC application in a solution, and inside the same solution there is another webservice project. I need to debug a particular WebGet method inside that service using a url in my localhost. Am able to reach the web service where it is hosted using the actual url to that service. But if I have to debug it, how can I reach that method when running in localhost?

Comment: Cannot understand the question. Please re-write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use IIS Express [How to: Specify the Web Server for Web Projects in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178108%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Using IIS express you can debug and run both projects in your solution at the same time.

[IIS Express for Developers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038)